# Wireless Keyboard not working with Mac Mini

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

I have the Apple Wireless Keyboard and a very recent Mac Mini. The keyboard exhibits very strange behaviour: meta keys / shortcuts such as CMD+TAB work, but none of the main letters do. Caps lock doesn't light up. Cursor keys work. Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Comment: Did you try new batteries already?

Comment: @patrix: yup, and battery level is reported at 100%